# Sending Multidimentional array data, with ajax, to a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have two simple scripts. One client-side jquery that has multidim array & a server-side php script. in php $data stays empty.

jquery

```
console.log("IN JQUERY");
console.log(inps);

$.ajax({
  type:           'post',
  cache:          false,
  url:            './gen.php',
  data:           inps,
  success: function(response){
    console.log("RESPONSE");
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

gen.php

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($data);
?>
```

firefox console output

```
>POST ..././gen.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1ms]
>"IN JQUERY" 
>{isbranch: "1", ismanager: "0", isdept: "1"} 
>"RESPONSE" 
>""
```

Is there a way to send Multi Dimensional array to the php with ajax without spliting array?

Comment: What do you  get from `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @kingero exact console-output : "<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JSON.stringify to encode your data before send it, also better to add correct contentType to it:

```
$.ajax({
  type:           'post',
  cache:          false,
  url:            '/gen.php',
  data:           JSON.stringify(inps),
  contentType:    'application/json',
  success: function(response){
    console.log("RESPONSE");
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: ...perfect
"IN JQUERY" test:515
{isbranch: "0", ismanager: "1", isdept: "0"} test:516
"RESPONSE" test:525
"Array
(
    [isbranch] => 0
    [ismanager] => 1
    [isdept] => 0
)
"

Answer (score 0):

The key-value pairs should already exist in your `$_POST`

```
$isbranch = $_POST['isbranch'];
$ismanager = $_POST['ismanager'];
$isdept = $_POST['isdept'];
```